# Convert Entity Property to String

Tags: entity

I am doing some work with my own `EntityStores` as well as the built in Wolfram Entities.  After pulling a subset of data, I am wanting to structure it as a dataset and to do so I need to be able to extract the property names to use as keys in an association thread.

It easy to get the Properties, but as you can see, the result comes out structured like an `Entity`.

[image: Properties]

I tried using `TextString` but essentially got the input form:

[image: TextString]

If I were dealing with the Entities themselves, I could use simply use ["Name:]

[image: Name]

I can do a work around with StringSplit, but that seems like a very round about way to do things.

```
StringSplit[#, {"[", ","}] & /@ 
  TextString /@ EntityProperties["Aircraft"][[All, 2]] // Flatten
```

Is there a solution that I am missing that doesn't require such Wolfram Gymnastics?

Comment: Doesn't already `EntityProperties["Aircraft"][[All , 2]]` give you what you want?

Comment: Wow... it does... I had no idea you could select a part of the variables of a function. Essentially that code would be: `EntityProperty["Aircraft","Ceiling"][[2]]`  which in fact returns "Ceiling".  I had only seen `Part` used with lists and not with functions.  Thanks for the simple solution!

Comment: Unless an expression is *atomic* (AtomQ), you can manipulate it like a `List` can be manipulated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue) instead:

```
EntityValue["Aircraft","PropertyCanonicalNames"]
```

> {"Ceiling", "Crew", "CruiseSpeed", "DesignedBy", "EmptyWeightPerBooster", 
>   "Height", "Image", "Introduced", "Length", "LoadedWeight", "MaidenFlight", 
>   "Manufacturer", "MaxSpeed", "MaxWeight", "Name", "NumberBuilt", "PowerPlant", 
>   "PowerPlantCount", "Range", "RateOfClimb", "Status", "Type", "WingArea", 
>   "WingLoading", "Wingspan"}

Another possibility is to use the function [`CanonicalName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName):

```
CanonicalName /@ EntityProperties["Aircraft"]
```

Also, for built-in entity types, you could use the subproperty "Dataset" to create a dataset:

```
EntityValue[
    EntityClass["Aircraft", "Harlow"],
    {"Ceiling", "Height", "Length"},
    "Dataset"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  That works great.  I was afraid it wouldn't work with my own `EntityStores` since they include very limited properties, but everything translates nicely.